# Cant delete certain folders with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, icacls

I have a problem when i want to delete profilefolders on a network share. There seems to be a problem with certain folders that cant be deleted.

Here is the code, which work fine on most folders:

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Users\mkz\Documents\powershell\modules\AlphaFS.2.1.3.0\Lib\Net452\AlphaFS.dll'

$folder = "\\filsrvm\MDrev\folderName"

#Function to take ownership and grant permissions
function takeOwnership($path)
{
    if(Test-Path $path)
    {
        $server = ($path).Split("\\",5)[2]+".adm.domain.dk"
        takeown.exe /S $server /F $path /r /d Y
        icacls $path /grant 'GroupAdm_GL:(CI)(OI)F' /t /c /q
        icacls "$path\*" /reset /t /c /q
    }
}

#Function to delete folders
function deleteFolder($path)
{

    if(Test-Path $path)
    {
        [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::Delete($path, $true, $true)
    }

}

takeOwnership($folder)
deleteFolder($folder)
```

I get the following error:

```
<red>Exception calling "Delete" with "3" argument(s): "(145) The directory is not empty: [\\?\UNC\filsrvm\MDrev\folderName\Ctx]"
At C:\Users\mkz\Documents\powershell\singleDelete.ps1:24 char:9
+         [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::Delete($path, $true ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmptyException</red>
```

I have tried to use `Remove-Item $path -force -Recurse` instead of "Alphaleonis" but it results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do this natively in PowerShell. [This solution](https://superuser.com/a/467814) worked for me on Windows Server 2012 R2. It roughly translates to PS as:

```
$pathToDelete = "TROUBLESOME_PATH_ROOT"
$tmpDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()
mkdir $tmpDir
& robocopy.exe /S /MIR $tmpDir "$pathToDelete"
rmdir $tmpDir
rmdir "$pathToDelete"
```

This recursively mirrors an empty directory to the target directory, effectively deleting it.

See also [How to delete directories with path/names too long for normal delete](https://superuser.com/a/1048242).

Comment: I tried it, but it i get an error. `rmdir : Parts of the path '\\filsrvm\filepath\to\remove' wasnt found.`

Comment: Sounds like RoboCopy completed successfully. You may need to run it more than once according to the links I cited although I haven't run into this myself. Are there files remaining in `$pathToDelete`?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but yes there are still files left in `$pathToDelete`. I have tried running it more than once and nothing seems to work. When i run robocopy after i have taken ownership i get the following error: `2018/07/17 08:18:52 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Deleting Extra Directory \\folder\to\delete
The specified file was not found.`

Comment: What if you put quotes around the `$pathToDelete` parameters above?

Comment: You mean around the variable like so: "$pathToDelete" ?What is the difference?

Comment: As far I remember rmdir is dos legacy and not intended to work with URL or network path. 
\\filsrvm\filepath\to\remove should be better written as z:\to\remove , of course after you invoked a net use, i.e. 
net use \\filsrvm\filepath z:
this is also useful to shorten the path, since it can happen that a command fail due to excessive length of the file or folder identification name.